# Can employers see who views a listing?

Tags: support, jobs, privacy

I'm curious what information an employer gets about who views their listings (of the viewers that are logged into the site).

- Do they see just a counter of page views?  (eg, "12345 people has viewed this")
- An aggregate view of tags people are interested in? (eg, "80% of people viewing this are interested in Java"...)
- Specific viewers? (eg, "Joe Schmoe and Jane Doe looked at this")

I suspect that it is not the latter, but I wanted to be sure.  It could be useful in many ways (allow employers to reach out to people who passively looked at their listing), but it would also be worrisome from a privacy perspective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently employers only see counting stats as you mentioned in point one with some additional stats on impressions at StackOverflow, Joel on Software etc... Search terms and tags people are interested in will be available to employers in the future, but aren't at this time.

I agree that showing specific viewers of a job listing could be a worrisome from a privacy standpoint.  We have no plans to do this, but are looking into better ways to match employers to candidates in a more passive way.

Comment: You could adopt a LinkedIn approach which allows candidates to be anonymous or passively show their card when viewing an ad